# Different queries or One? Which one is feasible?

Tags: oracle, sqlperformance

I have following queries where I want to delete 3 employees in Admin department.

```
Delete from Employee_tbl where emp_Id = 123 and emp_dep = 'Admin';
Delete from Employee_tbl where emp_Id = 456 and emp_dep = 'Admin';
Delete from Employee_tbl where emp_Id = 789 and emp_dep = 'Admin';
```

I am thinking to write a single query for this like-

```
Delete from Employee_tbl where emp_Id in (123, 456, 789) and emp_dep = 'Admin';
```

Is this the correct way to write this query in case of performance and all? I am confused.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The second option is simply better because you hit the table only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Queries have their pros and cons

**1) Multiple SELECTs.**

I would rather rewrite the query using bind variables.

```
Delete from Employee_tbl where emp_Id = :l_emp_id and emp_dep = :l_emp_dep;
```

And run it multiple times.

This way, oracle don't hard parse the query every time, and Oracle re-uses the explain plan reducing the latch activity in Shared Global Area(SGA) minimizing CPU usage.

More details from [Bind variables - The key to application performance](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html)

But one glitch here is, every execution of query actually, needs to switch from the client to SQL engine process.(Context Switching, which again is a costly process)

To override this, we use [`bulk binding`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS01205). But not all clients support this.

**2) Single Query using IN or Temp tables/CTE.**

This query simply depends on the `DB intelligence` itself. It is a no brainy for developers. The recent optimizers, handle them smartly, by internally, using [`IN-list iterators`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/opt_ops.htm#1004651) or temp tables if needed.

Other advantage would be, you run the query once, and the operation just needs one round trip to the database.

Let the database decide the load.